# How to make a route event layer?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, linear-referencing, route

I'm using ArcGis 10.1 but I'm a beginner in this program.

I want to make a route event layer based on a route I have already defined. 
My question is in the third line when the program ask me for an input event table. I read a couple of explanations about this tool but any of them explains what table is this. Do I have to create an excel table? If yes, how does it have to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply a table. This can be a .dbf file, a geodatabase table, or a sheet of an Excel file. I'd recommend exporting Excel/.dbf to a geodatabase table to make sure the field data types are converted properly.

After you've supplied the table, you will need to provide several fields (basically map your input table fields to the required in-fields). You can read what those fields mean here at the [Make Route Event Layer (Linear Referencing) help page](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//003m00000008000000).

If you are new to Linear Referencing, consider going through [ArcTutor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_linear_referencing_tutorial/003900000047000000/) tutorial which is shipped with your ArcGIS media. You can also download it from the Esri Customers Care portal.