# Line sections between points in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, point, line, linear-referencing

How to get shape with lines between points which have to lay on the same line entity?

[image]

Comment: Please **edit** this question to contain a great more detail (a couple of paragraphs) explaining what software you have (including version and relevant available extensions), what the data in the graphic represents, and what you are trying to accomplish. You should also indicate the programming interface you expect to use (UI, Python, ArcObjects,...). If you haven't taken the [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) yet, please do, since it will help you write questions that can be answered.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using [linear referencing](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.1/index.html#//003900000001000000).

1) After creating routes from you lines, you can extract the M value of those lines for each point using [locate feature along route](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Locate_Features_Along_Routes/003m00000007000000/).

2) With these value, create a table including the start and end M values for each line. (table join) make sure that you use the line ID to avoid using two points from different line entities.

3) Use [make route layer event](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94461/how-to-make-a-route-event-layer) to create the lines based on your table.

IF you have an advanced licence, you can also use another method.

1) Use "[split line at points](http://help.arcgis.com/EN/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003w000000)" to split your lines where you have a point.

2) Perform a spatial join with the result, and select by attribute the lines with 2 points. Those will be the lines that join two points on the same line.